# Can't edit a question due to "Title cannot contain [the original, unchanged title]"

Tags: bug, edits

I ran across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870702/jsonignore-not-working-for-boolean-field) and decided to edit it to improve a few things. After making some changes in the body (and not touching the title), I went to hit "Save Edits," but was given an error message:

> Title cannot contain "JsonIgnore not working for boolean field".
>
> Please provide a title that summarizes your question. For assistance, see: How do I ask a good question?

I think the title summarizes the question exactly as it should, and **I didn't change it**. Why can't I save my edits? What invisible title rule am I running into?

---

[image: Title error message]

---

## Update:

Adding '@' to the front allowed me to save my edits.

Doesn't work: JsonIgnore not working for boolean field

A-OK: @JsonIgnore not working for boolean field

Comment: I suspect "not working" is the think that trips the poor quality question checker.

Comment: See my update to the original question for a better way to deal with this.  As the editor, it's your responsibility to fix what the automation software deems a bad title (which, in fact, it was).

Comment: I don't see how your new title is "better." The title now points to Swagger, which doesn't factor in to the problem at all. It just happens to be the backstory for why he wants Jackson configured to stop serializing a field. So instead of a title that is focused on the actual problem (the behavior of the @JsonIgnore annotation when Jackson processes it), we have a red herring in the title.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to derail from the original question. Your comment about responsibility shifting to me as the editor is valuable in understanding the situation.

Comment: Then provide a better title than the one I chose.

Comment: Regarding your update, I don't think there's anything special about the '@' character, it just extended the length of the title to 41 characters.

Comment: Just encountered this error myself. It seems silly that you are blocked from making substantial edits if you cannot also rename the title, especially if the previous title was fine.