# Error when trying to save edit - Title cannot contain X

Tags: support, title, quality-filter

I tried to edit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743329/automation-error-in-vba) post. The title is "Automation Error in VBA." I did not modify the title at all but when I try to save the edit, I get the following error: Title cannot contain "Automation Error in VBA".

I have come across a [similar meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379684/cant-edit-a-question-due-to-title-cannot-contain-the-original-unchanged-titl) here which didn't contain an answer and was mistakenly marked as a duplicate. (The original question relates to getting the error after changing the title, not editing a post without making any change to the title)

Is there a way I can discover the cause of this kind of error?

Comment: The cause is that title filters are stricter than they used to be, and the new ones get applied when you edit a question.

Comment: Yeah, the error message leaves a lot to be desired. Just interpret it as if it were saying, "Please write a better, more descriptive title for this question."

Comment: So the title failed validation because it contains the work "error"?

Comment: Because it contains the word "error" and is under 40 characters, more specifically.

Comment: That is the most probable explanation, yes, especially since the title is so short. Extremely short titles that contain generic, non-descriptive words like "problem" and "error" tend to be caught by the regex and blocked by the system.